# Generate random colours with time-interval

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

i am working with an SKspritenode that is representing a ball. what i am busy doing is that i want the ball to change the colour after every time interval.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    ball.color = UIcolor.random()

    }
```

i'd say that code works well enough to change the colour. the problem however is that the colour changes every Frame witch much faster than i planned the colour change to be, like for each 2 seconds.

my workaround to this problem is listed below

```
var relative = 300

var Time = 0 {

    didSet {

        if Time == relative {

            ball.color = UIColor.random()
        }
    }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    PT.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.5))

    Time += 1

    if Time == relative {

        Time = 0
    }
}
```

so this code is designed to change the colour every Time == 300. while the value Time is updated every frame. then the Time value would reset = 0 when it reaches 300

this way i can change the colour after after seconds instead of every frame.

this design might look cheap and un-experinced way of coding and setting up functions to run. that is why i am asking any experienced programmer to sort of help me building a better way to design this logic. i am very new to functions and how they work, so please if any of you can learn me how to code a runnable, or self-containing function without relying interirely on "Swift built-in functions" like "Override function Update"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple modulus
`if currentTime % 300 == 0 { ball.color = UIColor.random() }`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change something with a specific time you could calculate the delta time first and sum that to create a "realtime" timer. The delta time is the time that went by since the last call of the update method and it is a often used method to update entities and components.

After the value is above for example 1000ms simply call your random color function and reset the timer.

```
//prevent from starting with a 0 time interval by using optional
var lastUpdateTimeInterval: CFTimeInterval?
var timer: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    var delta: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
    if let luti = lastUpdateTimeInterval {
        delta = currentTime - luti
    }

    //use delta for update logic like entitys.update(delta)
    timer += delta

    if timer > 1 { //after 1s
        ball.color = UIColor.random()
        timer = 0.0 //reset timer
    }

    lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime
}
```

Comment: that didn't work. i guess its because the timer doesn't get assigned any value

Comment: @user3211359 `var timer: CFTimeInterval = 0.0` is an assignment and `timer += delta` does add the delta to it. If you don't a delta time you do not pass the currentTime properly.

Comment: i did assign the timer. problem is, the timer looks somehow like this

0.0166666669974802 - luti
26790.488545286 - delta

Comment: Right. Frametime is 16.6666ms so it does make sense that it is 0.016. change the timer compare from 1000 to 1 since 1 is one second and not 1000. calculated in s not in ms. My fault.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If it solved your problem please accept the answer.